# create variables that that are calculated from possible combinations of various other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a big database where each row is a segment of text that has been coded with codes belonging to 4 different dimensions. I want to create a new variable to output possible combinations.

Example:

```
Recipe  <-c("ndfkkjd nsakjfbk slgnjkdf", "bffhsbk sbfksdhbk, kbvkbdsk", "asbkdbask", "ouwehowq", "yeueyye fbhfbj")
Origin  <-c("Morocco", "Spain", "France", "Spain", "Italy")
Water   <-c(1,1,0,1, 1)
Oil     <-c(0,0,1,0,0)
Broth   <-c(0,0,1,1,1)
Chicken <-c(1,1,0,0,0)
df <- tibble::tibble(Recipe=Recipe, Origin=Origin, Broth=Broth, Chicken=Chicken, Oil=Oil, Water=Water)
```

I want to have a variable that shows the possible combinations of either water or oil, with either broth or chicken. Obviously my database is way larger, and the possible combinations extend to (13 combined with 35), so I really need to do it automatedly. I know that the sum of these variables can never be higher than 2 (ie. not containing more than two ingredients). My desired output should look as follows:

```
`Broth+Oil`     <- c(0,0,1,0,0)
`Broth+Water`   <- c(0,0,0,1,1)
`Chicken+Oil`   <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
`Chicken+Water` <- c(1,1,0,0,0)
df2 <- tibble(`Broth+Oil`,
              `Broth+Water`,
              `Chicken+Oil`,
              `Chicken+Water`)
df3 <- cbind(df, df2)
```

so far I just created a vector with all the possible combinations, but I don't really knwo how to evn start thinking about it.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you're looking for, but I'll give it a try. I'll give you a couple of solution, choose the one you need.

First of all, your df:

```
Recipe <- c("ndfkkjd nsakjfbk slgnjkdf", "bffhsbk sbfksdhbk, kbvkbdsk", "asbkdbask", "ouwehowq", "yeueyye fbhfbj")
Origin <- c("Morocco", "Spain", "France", "Spain", "Italy")
Water <- c(1,1,0,1, 1)
Oil <- c(0,0,1,0,0)
Broth <- c(0,0,1,1,1)
Chicken <- c(1,1,0,0,0)
df <- tibble::tibble(Recipe=Recipe, Origin=Origin, Broth=Broth, Chicken=Chicken, Oil=Oil, Water=Water)
```

FIRST SOLUTION

Let's create a column that shows the combination of two ingredients.

We do it the old good apply and by transforming your dataframe into a matrix of logical values.
This solution doesn't care how many columns you have, neither whether the sum for each row is 2 or more.

```
cols <- c("Broth", "Chicken", "Oil", "Water")

df$comb <- apply(df[cols] == 1, 1, function(x) paste(cols[x], collapse = "+"))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#> Recipe                      Origin  Broth Chicken   Oil Water comb         
#> <chr>                       <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
#> 1 ndfkkjd nsakjfbk slgnjkdf   Morocco     0       1     0     1 Chicken+Water
#> 2 bffhsbk sbfksdhbk, kbvkbdsk Spain       0       1     0     1 Chicken+Water
#> 3 asbkdbask                   France      1       0     1     0 Broth+Oil    
#> 4 ouwehowq                    Spain       1       0     0     1 Broth+Water  
#> 5 yeueyye fbhfbj              Italy       1       0     0     1 Broth+Water
```

SECOND SOLUTION

This is to get the same solution that @c0rias is proposing:

```
library(tidyr)
cols <- c("Broth", "Chicken", "Oil", "Water")
df$comb <- apply(df[cols] == 1, 1, function(x) paste(cols[x], collapse = "+"))
df$dummy <- 1
df %>% spread(comb, dummy, fill = 0)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 9
#> Recipe                      Origin  Broth Chicken   Oil Water `Broth+Oil` `Broth+Water` `Chicken+Water`
#> <chr>                       <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 asbkdbask                   France      1       0     1     0           1             0               0
#> 2 bffhsbk sbfksdhbk, kbvkbdsk Spain       0       1     0     1           0             0               1
#> 3 ndfkkjd nsakjfbk slgnjkdf   Morocco     0       1     0     1           0             0               1
#> 4 ouwehowq                    Spain       1       0     0     1           0             1               0
#> 5 yeueyye fbhfbj              Italy       1       0     0     1           0             1               0
```

THIRD SOLUTION

But to get exactly df3 you need something slightly different, because so far a combination theoretically possible that didn't show up in the data couldn't appear (talking about Chicken+Oil).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
cols <- c("Broth", "Chicken", "Oil", "Water")

# get actual combination
res <- apply(df[cols] == 1, 1, function(x) paste(cols[x], collapse = "+"))

# get all possible combination
comb <- expand.grid(col1, col2) %>% pmap_chr(paste, sep = "+")

# create a factor
df$comb <- factor(res, level = comb)

# complete and spread
df$dummy <- 1
df %>% complete(comb) %>% spread(comb, dummy, fill = 0) %>% semi_join(df)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#> Recipe           Origin Broth Chicken   Oil Water `Broth+Oil` `Chicken+Oil` `Broth+Water` `Chicken+Water`
#> <chr>            <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 asbkdbask        France     1       0     1     0           1             0             0               0
#> 2 bffhsbk sbfksdh~ Spain      0       1     0     1           0             0             0               1
#> 3 ndfkkjd nsakjfb~ Moroc~     0       1     0     1           0             0             0               1
#> 4 ouwehowq         Spain      1       0     0     1           0             0             1               0
#> 5 yeueyye fbhfbj   Italy      1       0     0     1           0             0             1               0
```

Unfortunately, before tidyr 1.0.0 you could have just used instead of that last line:

```
df %>% spread(comb, dummy, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
```

But now they have changed the mechanics of spread.. What I showed is something usable, but I don't find it really efficient for large data.

EDIT: you can achieve the THIRD SOLUTION with this:

```
library(purrr)
cols <- c("Broth", "Chicken", "Oil", "Water")

# get all possible combination
comb <- expand.grid(col1, col2) %>% pmap_chr(paste, sep = "+")

# get actual combination and compare with possible comb
df[comb] <- as.numeric(t(apply(df[cols] == 1, 1,
                               function(x) comb == paste(cols[x], collapse = "+"))))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#> Recipe           Origin Broth Chicken   Oil Water `Broth+Oil` `Chicken+Oil` `Broth+Water` `Chicken+Water`
#> <chr>            <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 ndfkkjd nsakjfb~ Moroc~     0       1     0     1           0             0             0               1
#> 2 bffhsbk sbfksdh~ Spain      0       1     0     1           0             0             0               1
#> 3 asbkdbask        France     1       0     1     0           1             0             0               0
#> 4 ouwehowq         Spain      1       0     0     1           0             0             1               0
#> 5 yeueyye fbhfbj   Italy      1       0     0     1           0             0             1               0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually thought that getting all the theoretically possible solutions would be easier in R, but I am actually only interested in the real combinations, so Solution 2 is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can obtain the combinations you want to have by elongating your tibble, filter for 1 entries, combine them, and widen your tibble again.

Have a look at this, please:

```
library(tidyverse)

# First batch of variables
cols1 <- c("Water", "Oil")

#Second batch of variables
cols2 <-  c("Broth", "Chicken")

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = cols1, names_to = "col1", values_to = "ind_1") %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = cols2, names_to = "col2", values_to = "ind_2") %>% 
    filter(ind_1 == 1 & ind_2 == 1) %>% 
    mutate(combined = paste(col1, ' + ', col2)) %>% 
    select(Recipe, Origin, combined) %>% 
    mutate(dummy = 1) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = combined,
                values_from = dummy,
                values_fill = list(dummy = 0))
```

If you have any questions or if I am totally off, please let me know!